# Why "respect you most" instead of "respect you more" in the following quote by Samuel Johnson?

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree, degree-of-comparison

"Go into the street and give one man a lecture on morality and another a shilling, and see which will respect you most." [British Literature 1640-1789](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=2wp0CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1052&dq=go+into+the+street+and+give+one+man+a+lecture+on+morality&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji85e9rpzNAhUHTJAKHf7CBl04ChDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=go%20into%20the%20street%20and%20give%20one%20man%20a%20lecture%20on%20morality&f=false)

I can't figure out why Johnson used "most" instead of "more".   Am I missing something here? Is it grammatical as it is?

Comment: The language has changed over the last 200years and using most gives the sentence a better meter with a punchier ending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two scenarios.

1. A man who received a shilling respects you more than the other man (who was lectured) respects you.
2. A man who received a shilling respects you 100% wholeheartedly and the other man respects you only 50% halfheartedly.

If you write the sentence based on the first scenario, I think using "more" is more appropriate. However, if it is based on the second scenario, I don't see any reason why the superlative can't be used for the sentence.

I think the adverb [*most*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/most) in your example means

> To the greatest extent

For example:

A: Who do you like more between Adel and Taylor Swift?

B: I like Adel more than (I like) Taylor Swift. (comparison )

A: Who do you like most between Adel and Taylor Swift?

B: I like Taylor Swift most (to the maximum extent that I can possibly like any person)

I could be wrong, but this is the way I understand the difference.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how the difference between these two scenarios would affect the sentence in the question, since it seems to be explicitly limited in scope to the two men ("see **which** will respect you the most"). And as far as I know, when there are only two things being compared, we don't use "most" even if one of them is at the maximum. I don't have any better ideas, though... this is a good attempt at an answer.

Comment: @sumelic The way I see it is it is used for emphasis for the degree as other superlatives such as "best" are used. I don't think it is impossible to use "best" when you compare only two things.